# How to independently delete dynamically-added input fields in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, forms, dynamic

I'm trying to independently delete dynamic inputs in a form in React. I have a user attribute group, and then user attribute children. I need to be able to dynamically add new user attribute groups and children, but then delete those fields without deleting ALL of the child attributes.

Right now, when I delete a child attribute, it deletes one from EACH user attribute group.

I have a working fiddle here that shows my code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/23kr654w80

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Input, Row, Col, Form, FormGroup, Label } from "reactstrap";

class OfferCriteria extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      single: "",
      attributeSingle: [{ single: "" }],
      child: "",
      attributeChild: [{ child: " " }]
    };
  }
  handleNameChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handleAddSingleAttribute = () => {
    this.setState({
      attributeSingle: this.state.attributeSingle.concat([{ name: "" }])
    });
  };

  handleRemoveSingleAttribute = idx => () => {
    this.setState({
      attributeSingle: this.state.attributeSingle.filter(
        (s, sidx) => idx !== sidx
      )
    });
  };

  handleAddChildAttribute = () => {
    this.setState({
      attributeChild: this.state.attributeChild.concat([{ child: "" }])
    });
  };

  handleRemoveChildAttribute = idz => () => {
    this.setState({
      attributeChild: this.state.attributeChild.filter(sidz => idz !== sidz)
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Col lg="10">
            <hr />
          </Col>
          <Col lg="2" className="float-right">
            <Button color="success" onClick={this.handleAddSingleAttribute}>
              Add Attribute Group
            </Button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        {this.state.attributeSingle.map(() => (
          <div>
            <br />
            <Row>
              <Col lg="2">
                <Label>User Attributes</Label>
              </Col>
              <Col lg="3" className="float-left">
                <FormGroup check inline>
                  <Input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="radio"
                    id="includeUserAttributes"
                    name="inline-radios"
                    value="includeUserAttributes"
                  />
                  <Label
                    className="form-check-label"
                    check
                    htmlFor="inline-radio1"
                  >
                    Include
                  </Label>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check inline>
                  <Input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="radio"
                    id="excludeUserAttributes"
                    name="inline-radios"
                    value="excludeUserAttributes"
                  />
                  <Label
                    className="form-check-label"
                    check
                    htmlFor="inline-radio2"
                  >
                    Exclude
                  </Label>
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>
              <Col lg="4">
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="text-input"
                  placeholder="This is parent attribute"
                />
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <br />
            <Row>
              <Col lg="3">
                {this.state.attributeChild.map(() => (
                  <div className="shareholder">
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      name="text-input"
                      placeholder="This is child attribute"
                    />
                  </div>
                ))}
              </Col>

              <Col lg="3" className="float-right">
                {this.state.attributeChild.map(() => (
                  <div className="shareholder">
                    <Button
                      color="primary"
                      onClick={this.handleAddChildAttribute}
                    >
                      Add Attribute Child
                    </Button>
                    <br />
                  </div>
                ))}
              </Col>
              <Col lg="3" className="float-right">
                {this.state.attributeChild.map(idz => (
                  <div className="shareholder">
                    <Button
                      color="danger"
                      onClick={this.handleRemoveChildAttribute(idz)}
                    >
                      Remove Attribute Child
                    </Button>
                    <br />
                  </div>
                ))}
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <hr />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default OfferCriteria;
```

I need these child attributes to delete ONLY in their parent attribute group, instead of deleting all of them from all the attribute groups.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going wrong with your code, but I'll focus on your initial question.

The problem is that you use the same array of `child` for all your groups. In order to be correct, you should include the `attributeChild` state into the attributeSingle objects :

```
{
  attributeSingle: [
    { 
      single: "", 
      attributeChild: [
        { 
          child: " " 
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

That way, children remain independent between groups.

Comment: what else do you see wrong with the code? this snippet doesn't appear to work when incorporated into the existing code

Comment: Absolutely, adaptations are required in order for the code to work. Fixing this problem consists in going through your entire app to adapt references to the new state and correct state updates. I encourage you to try and do it yourself instead of asking someone else to do it for you :)

Comment: No judgment at all. I did provide you insight by pointing out the root cause of your issue. I believe that you will get most value out of it if you try to do the rest yourself instead of just copy-pasting a solution. If you have trouble doing so, I'm here to help

Comment: I have tried to change the file and state manipulation but have had no luck.